# Member function callback

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, function-pointers

Present is a class to register functions as callbacks.

```
class Action {
private:
    static std::multimap<std::string, std::function<void()>> actions;
public:
    static void registerAction(const std::string &key, std::function<void()> action);
}
```

Obviously it can not register member functions, as function pointer objects to member functions require the class to be specified, but every class should be able to register their  functions. `std::function<void(Class&)>`

Using a template system, I couldn't access all actions from one "instance" of the static class I suppose. How could this be realized?

*Example how it should look like:*

```
class B {
public:
    B() {
        Action::registerAction("some_action", &callMe);
    }

    void callMe(){}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that member functions taken an additional argument, you need to bind this argument. For example, you could use something like this:

```
Action::registerAction("come_action", std::bind(&callMe, this));
```

The `bind()` expression will created a function object taking no arguments. Obviously, for this approach to work, `this` needs to stick around long enough.

Comment: Just asking: Is it safe to do: `Action::registerAction(..., reinterpret_cast<void (*)()>(&callMe));`

Comment: @0x499602D2: just answering: no. Aside from not being safe it also won't work.

Comment: @0x499602D2: try calling the function and use a member of your object (if you don't need to use a member, you could make the function `static` and you wouldn't need to use a cast at all). The fact your managed to produce a pointer doesn't show anything.

Comment: @0x499602D2: just for completeness, the relevant section is 5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast] paragraph 6, second sentence: "The effect of calling a function through a pointer to a function type (8.3.5) that is not the same as the type used in the definition of the function is undefined."

Answer (score 3):

you could use std::bind or a lambda function

```
// std::bind
Action::registerAction( "bla", std::bind(&callMe, this) );

// lambda
Action::registerAction( "bla", [this]() { this->callMe(); } );
```

i would suggest reading up on lambda functions. Pretty easy to use, and much more powerful than std::bind.

Comment: And they're usually more easy to inline by the compiler, though in this case it shouldn't matter.